# How to set the page width in R Shiny?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have a `fluidPage` with a `sidebarLayout`. In the `mainPanel`, I have a very wide `dataTableOutput` (in a `tabPanel`).

Currently, the columns are being squished together and each row is text-wrapped to span many lines. However, I want each row of the table **not to be text-wrapped** and to **enable horizontal scrolling** on the page.

**Minimal working example:**

```
library(shiny)
nrow <- 20; ncol <- 26
runApp(list(
    ui = fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(helpText("Hello world")),
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table"))
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$table <- renderDataTable(
            as.data.frame(
                matrix(nrow = nrow,
                    rep("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", nrow*ncol)
                )
            )
        )
    }
))
```

...which outputs:

[image]

Now, how to prevent "*The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*" from being text-wrapped and so occupy just a single line?

Is there some option I can set to **make the page wider**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surrond your tabpanel with a div giving a width. Add some css to change the max-width of a fluid container

```
library(shiny)
nrow <- 20; ncol <- 26
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(helpText("Hello world")),
      mainPanel(

        tabsetPanel(
          div(tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table")), style = 'width:5500px;')
        )
        , 
        tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", ".container-fluid {  max-width: 12600px; /* or 950px */}"))
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      as.data.frame(
        matrix(nrow = nrow,
               rep("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", nrow*ncol)
        )
      )
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the div from enclosing the `tabPanel` to enclose the tabPanel contents as illustrated below:

```
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Table", div(dataTableOutput("table"), style = 'width:5500px;'))
    tabPanel("Table2", div(dataTableOutput("table2"), style = 'width:5500px;'))
    )
```

enclosing the tabPanels inside the div, results in a single tabPanel containing both tables instead of two tabPanels each containing one table.